# Haskell - Why do multiple declarations not work?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to do a task, but when I tried to do this:

```
data Fruit  = Pear | Orange | Apple | Banana
data Colour = Red | Orange | Yellow | Green
```

I got an error. What is the problem? Why can I not use `Orange` twice?

Comment: "What is the problem? Why can I not use "Orange" twice?" Sounds like you already answered the first question. The second "why" is probably a fair question though. (In short it's because the compiler won't later know which one you mean if you use `Orange` somewhere.)

Comment: To elaborate, defining `x = Orange` would not allow Haskell to infer the type of `x`. Similarly, defining a function by cases as in `f Orange = True ; f _ = False` would not allow Haskell to infer the type of `f`. Theoretically, one could allow this by using more sophisticated types, but the additional complexity it would bring is too much compared with the very minor benefit.

Answer (score 4):

The comments already discussed matters like “the compiler won't later know which one you mean” and “would not allow Haskell to infer the type”. Which are true.

But at its most basic, this is just the same problem as when you write code like

```
x :: Int
x = 4
x = 9
```

Or, in a C-like language

```
void foo() {
  printf("this");
}
void foo() {
  printf("that");
}
```

– in all these examples you are twice defining something with the same name but doing different things. Specifically, with two constructors that are both called `Orange`, you're under the hood defining all of the following:

```
data Fruit  = Fruit0 | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3

pear, orange, apple, banana :: Fruit
pear = Fruit0
orange = Fruit1
apple = Fruit2
banana = Fruit3

data Colour = Colour0 | Colour1 | Colour2 | Colour3

red, orange, yellow, green :: Colour
red = Colour0
orange = Colour1
yellow = Colour2
green = Colour3
```

(And even more, since constructors can also *de*construct, by pattern matching.)

The more interesting question is actually: why do other languages allow you to write things like this?

```
struct Fruit {
  peariness, orangeness, appleness, banananess :: Float
};
struct Colour {
  redness, orangeness, yellowness, greenness :: Float
};
```

What's happening here is that a struct / class in OO languages declares simultaneously a new type, and a new *namespace*. And `orangeness` in the `Fruit` class is just the unqualified form of `Fruit/orangeness` (or `Fruit::orangeness`, in C++ syntax).

Haskell has namespaces too, but *exclusively* in the form of modules. It is perfectly ok to have (in three separate files)

```
module Fruit where

data Fruit  = Pear | Orange | Apple | Banana
  deriving (Show)

module Colour where

data Colour = Red | Orange | Yellow | Green
  deriving (Show)

module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print Fruit.Orange
  print Colour.Orange
```